# How can I print readme file in git wiki

Tags: git, gitlab, markup

I have a git wiki where I want to store documentation but I don't want to keep editing it so I wonder if it's possible to show context of README.md located in my git repository. I managed to URL link to it, but I want to show context of the file right there so that the only thing that I will keep editing is the readme file inside my branch.
I didn't find a way that markup allows me to this, and I didn't have much luck finding a similar problem on stackoverflow. Would it be possible to do something like this?

Comment: Do you mean like embedding the file somewhere? Or where do you want to display it? Also, are you using Github or Gitlab? Because you tagged both.

Comment: My bad, I want to display the context in gitlab wiki page.